# Passar parâmetros no GET

Tags: json, orientação-a-objetos, restful, get, gson

Estou tentando fazer um GET para validar um usuário usando o cpf e senha,usando o DAO, porém estou com dúvida na hora de passar o parâmetro.

Segue o codigo get

```
   private Usuario usuarioLogado;

    @GET
    @Path("/{cpf}/{senha}")
    public String Autenticar(@PathParam("cpf") String cpf,@PathParam("senha") String senha  ) {

    UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
    usuarioLogado = usuarioDAO.autenticar(cpf, senha);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(usuarioLogado);

        return json; }
```

Segue o DAO

```
public Usuario autenticar(String cpf, String senha) {
        Session sessao = hibernateUtil.getFabricaDeSessoes().openSession();

        try{
            Criteria consulta = sessao.createCriteria(Usuario.class);
            consulta.createAlias("pessoa", "p");

            consulta.add(Restrictions.eq("p.cpf", cpf));

            SimpleHash hash = new SimpleHash("md5", senha);
            consulta.add(Restrictions.eq("senha", hash.toHex()));

            Usuario resultado = (Usuario) consulta.uniqueResult();

            return resultado;
        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            throw erro;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: E qual sua dúvida?

Comment: De qualquer forma é uma péssima prática você passar a senha aberta através da URL do seu GET.

Comment: Então, isto que imaginei, e queria saber como eu poderei fazer esta autenticação sem passar na URL a senha.

Comment: A minha dúvida é se teria outra forma de se fazer esta consulta de autenticação.

Answer (score 0):

Como você precisa enviar usuário e senha, em vez de utilizar um GET você deveria utilizar POST, pq ué já evita que o usuário e senha apareçam na URL.

Mesmo assim, você precisa utilizar https para submeter esse formulário de usuário e senha, caso contrário alguém pode interceptar a comunicação de rede e obter o conteúdo do post, junto co usuário e senha.